# Laurent Series of $\frac{1}{(z-2)(z+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, laurent-series

$$\frac{1}{(z-2)(z+1)}=\frac{A}{z-2}+\frac{B}{z+1}$$

\begin{cases}A+B=0 \\ A-2B=1
\end{cases}

$$A=\frac{1}{3} \\ B=-\frac{1}{3}$$

$$\frac{1}{(z-2)(z+1)}=\frac{\frac{1}{3}}{z-2}+\frac{-\frac{1}{3}}{z+1}$$

Laurent Series $$\rvert z \rvert <1$$

$$\frac{1}{(z-2)(z+1)}=-\frac{1}{6} \ \frac{1}{-\frac{z}{2}+1}-\frac{1}{3} \ \frac{1}{1-(-z)}= \\=-\frac{1}{6} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (\frac{z}{2})^n-\frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-z)^n  $$

$$1 < \rvert z \rvert <2$$

$$\frac{1}{(z-2)(z+1)}=-\frac{1}{6} \ \frac{1}{-\frac{z}{2}+1}-\frac{1}{3} \ \frac{1}{z(1-(-\frac{1}{z}) )}= \\ \\ = -\frac{1}{6} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (\frac{z}{2})^n-\frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-\frac{1}{z})^{n+1} $$

$$ \rvert z \rvert >2$$

$$\frac{1}{(z-2)(z+1)}=\frac{1}{3} \ \frac{1}{z(1-\frac{2}{z})}-\frac{1}{3} \ \frac{1}{z(1-(-\frac{1}{z}) )}= \\ \\ = \frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (\frac{2}{z})^{n+1}-\frac{1}{3} \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} (-\frac{1}{z})^{n+1} $$

Is it correct?

Thanks!

Comment: I think these are OK. good job.