# Finding Laurent series expansion of $f(z) = \frac{z}{(z−1)(2−z)}$ where $|z-1| > 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

Write the Laurent series expansion of $f(z) = \frac{z}{(z−1)(2−z)}$ where $|z− 1| > 1$.

I am learning complex analysis by myself in this pandemic, but I am not able to solve this problem. Please help me to solve it.

Comment: Hint: $f(z)=\frac  z {z-1}+\frac z {2-z}$.

Comment: Partial Fractions...

Comment: This has been asked several times before, for example (with answer in the question) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120861/laurent-series-of-frac1z-2z1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(z)=\frac{z}{(z-1)(2-z)}=\frac{z}{z-1}+\frac{z}{2-z}=\frac{z}{z-1}+\frac{z}{1+(1-z)}$$ $$=\frac{z}{z-1}+\frac{z}{(1-z)[1-(-\frac{1}{1-z})]}$$ $$=\frac{z}{z-1}+\frac{z}{1-z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{1}{(1-z)^n}$$ $$=\frac{z}{z-1}+\frac{z}{1-z} +\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{z}{(1-z)^{n+1}}$$ $$=-\sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{z}{(z-1)^n}$$

Comment: The question is about finding the series $\sum_n c_n (z - 1)^n$, with $c_n$ independent of $z$.

Comment: I agree with @Maxim . This does not seem to answer the question